# How do you open an appx or appxupload file?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, msbuild, windows-store-apps

I used `msbuild.exe` to build a cordova app that generated a load of files with extensions i've not seen before. I'm trying to build an app for the windows app (metro?) screen. This can be done in Visual Studio but i'd like to be able to build and run the app via a gulp command.

After some research I *think* what I'm looking for is the appx or appxupload file? I managed to find one of each in the build directory but they don't know how to open- in that, windows asks me "what should I open this file with?".

How do I open these files so I can view the app in the windows app view? (or are these even the files I'm looking for?)

Answer (score 1):

The appx file is a package that needs to be installed. Typically you would upload this (the appxinstall) to the store and then install it from there, but for testing or private deployment you can install them with power shell's add-appxpackage command or through an MDM solution such as InTune.

See [Packaging and deployment tools and PowerShell cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446592(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Windows 8.1 Store apps: Install and test an app on other devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975356.aspx)